# Regarding the preimage of the Gauss–Kuzmin–Wirsing operator

Tags: number-theory, functions

In lecture we defined the Gauss–Kuzmin–Wirsing operator $\tau(x)$ via $\tau(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \big\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \big\rfloor$ for $x > 0$ and $\tau(0) = 0$ for $x = 0$. We noted that for any $[a,b] \subseteq (0,1)$ it holds

$$\tau^{-1}([a,b]) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigg[\frac{1}{b+n},\frac{1}{a+n}\bigg].$$

I get that for the continued fraction expansion of a real number $x = [0;a_1,a_2,\ldots]$ holds $\tau(x) = [0;a_2,a_3,\ldots]$, but I do not understand why this identity for the preimage holds. Could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x>0$ is such that $\tau (x)\in[a,b]$ then we must have $a\le \frac{1}{x}-\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor\le b$. Remembering how the integer part is defined, this means that $\frac{1}{x}=n+\alpha$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}, n=\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor$ and $a\le\alpha\le b$. So $x=\frac{1}{n+\alpha}$, and indeed every number of this form is such that $\tau (x)\in[a,b]$. Now just notice that for a given $n$ the set of all values of $x$ such that $x=\frac{1}{n+\alpha}$ with $a\le\alpha\le b$ is $[\frac{1}{b+n},\frac{1}{a+n}]$, and finally you just have to take the union for all values of $n$.